# Hacker rank minimax problem, maximum sum giving wrong negative values

Tags: c++, c++14

I am currently solving this problem on Hackerrank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem

I passed only 5 out of the 15 test cases. The problem is in the output of the maximum sum.

In the code, first I am finding the maximum and minimum element in the vector, denoted by max and min. minI and maxI are the indexes of the minimum and maximium value.

When calculating the max sum, I put arr[minI] = 0 (So the vector is reduced to elements which will give a maximum sum). Once the max sum is obtained, I put arr[minI] = min, hence restoring the original vector. Then I repeat the process by putting arr[maxI] = 0; in this way both the min and max sum of n-1 elements is obtained. I know it is hard to understand but can anyone please help me figure out the problem here.

I tried using arr.erase() and arr.insert() but that got me into issues with indexing.

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
int max = arr[0];
int min = arr[0];
int minI = 0;
int maxI = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if(arr[i] > max){
        max = arr[i];
        maxI = i;
    }
    if(arr[i] < min){
        min = arr[i];
        minI = i;
    }
  }


  arr[minI] = 0;
  int maxsum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++){
      maxsum += arr[i];
  }

  arr[minI] = min;


  arr[maxI] = 0;
  int minsum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++){
      minsum += arr[i];
  }


  cout << minsum << " " << maxsum;
}
```

For instance the input of one test case was:

140537896 243908675 670291834 923018467 520718469

The correct answer of the above input is:
1575456874 2357937445

My answer for the above input is:
1575456874 -1937029851

Comment: Without knowing the concrete testcases this is impossible to answer here. As a general advice: Don't waste your time at online code judge engines like _hackerrank_.

Comment: You can paste my code on the above given link and after submitting the code, you will be able to see the test cases.

Comment: Do you know what the range of valid values is for an integer in C++ is? That might give you a clue.

Comment: Where else should I practice and improve my problem solving skills?

Comment: ***Where else should I practice and improve my problem solving skills?*** I think it depends on what you want to do as a programmer. If your main objective is to get a job as a programmer I would say to avoid these sites. They will teach you a lot of bad practices that are not very compatible with working as a software developer. Instead help out on a open source project that interests you on github. Also at least for me the problems you solve in these sites are not very representative in what I have done as a professional developer for my 22 years that I have been paid to code..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Dude no need to, the ones really interested in helping me solved my problem, which was such a silly one.

Comment: @drescherjm, I just want to improve my problem solving skills. In future, I plan to get into AI/ML.

Comment: Unrelated to problem. But you can solve this problem with only one iteration over the vector, see [this example](http://cpp.sh/8ov22)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah my bad, but it did help me solve the problem, I'll probably delete this question.

Comment: @MohammadHaris _"I'll probably delete this question."_ Good idea!

Comment: @Neijwiert Wow that is pretty cool. I know my code was poor in terms of complexity and fluency

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  i won't agree with you, these websites help you to write the efficient, less timely and large scale solution. it's like we can add numbers 0 to 10^9 one by one ,or just use the formula

Comment: @MohammadHaris it's easy problem all you have to do is sort the data and get sum of first 4 and last 4 elements

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, on this platform `int` is 32-bit long, which means it has range between `-2147483647` to `2137483647`. Overflowing the maximum value is Undefined Behaviour.

It seems that for the test case you presented it will be enough to change `int` to `long long`, but it is possible that problem will require even bigger numbers and you will need to work out how to perform calculations on bigger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Negative sums after adding positive integers nearly always pinpoint the problem: you are getting an overflow.

This problem has a constraint:

```
1 <= arr[i] <= 10^9
```

When you add four numbers that are close to 10^9, you overflow a 32-bit integer. Hence you need to switch to a larger data type - `uint64_t` would be a good candidate.

**Note:** The problem asks for min and max sum of exactly four of the five elements, which means that exactly one element needs to be excluded. It follows that the sum would be maximal if you subtract the smallest element from the total of five elements; when you subtract the largest element, the sum would be minimal.

Comment: @MohammadHaris That's great! Now see if you can solve it with a single line of code (hint: use standard C++ library, functions `min_element`, `max_element`, and `accumulate`).

Comment: Alright I'm on it, actually not that fluent with C++ so don't know much of the built-in functions.

Comment: @Alex Done :-) :-) :-)